# Lazy loading feature modules with multiple components doesn't work in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a `customer` module with `customer-routing` module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: CustomerComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'edit', component: EditCustomerComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

And this is my `app-routing` module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'customers/:id', loadChildren: './customer/customer.module#CustomerModule' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent}
];
```

But when I follow such path `customers/3/edit` it shows me always `CustomerComponent` not `EditCustomerComponent`.

Maybe lazy loading doesn't work?

PS: I am using angular 6.1.0

**Update:** My customer module

```
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {CustomerComponent} from './customer.component';
import {EditCustomerComponent} from './edit-customer.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CustomerRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [CustomerComponent, EditCustomerComponent]
})
export class CustomerModule { }
```

Comment: Can you [enable tracing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45669041/2131286) and show the output?

Comment: also, how is defined your CustomerModule?

Comment: @LazarLjubenović Added this config but I dont see anything in console

Comment: @Pac0 Added my customer module

Comment: Do you have a router-outlet inside the HTML of CustomerComponent ? For me the router configuration seem to be fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to put edit route under children. Your customer-routing module would simply look like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: CustomerComponent },
  { path: 'edit', component: EditCustomerComponent }
];
```

Also make sure to check whether this routes array has been imported using forChild function in your customer-routing module like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CustomerRoutingModule { }
```

Hope this should solve your routing issue.