# How can I use get parameter from URL with router in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular7

I am really confused by the Angular 7 router. I want to use the get parameter "token" from any place in the URL.

I use the following code to define several routes.

```
const myRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'register/:token', component: RegisterComponent },
// { path: 'register?token=:token', component: RegisterComponent },
// { path: 'register:token', component: RegisterComponent },
{ path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
// ...
]
```

With the first defined path I am able to use "register/*mytoken*" and "register/?token=*mytoken*" to get the token.

```
// Token from register/123
this.token = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('token')
// Token from register/?token=123
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  if (params.token != null)
    this.token = params.token;
});
```

Any time i try to provide my token directly as get-parameter when calling the website in my browser ("register?token=*mytoken*"), the router will redirect me to "/register" and I can't get the token with my code above. But when i use "register/?token=*mytoken*" i will be redirected to "register?token=*mytoken*" and can use the token.

How can i provide a route for accessing the page with "register?token=123" and retrieve the token?

Comment: Tested your code and it works with `http://localhost:4200/register?token=123` and `http://localhost:4200/register/?token=123` for me. So the code you give doesn't seems to be the problem. But just in case, did you try to change order of these paths ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Gilsdav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7511690/gilsdav), I should have tested this in a "clean" project by myself. I found some block of code from my colleague, which interferes with the get parameter of the router:

```
var loc = window.location.pathname;    
if ((loc == "/register") || (loc == "/"))  {
  this.router.navigate(['/landing']);
}
```

This redirect strips the get parameters. 
I could verify the redirect by his code by adding [*{enableTracing:true}*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45669030/how-to-trace-routing-in-angular-2).

```
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      routes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
]
```