# routerLink in angular sends me to a blank page

Tags: angular, typescript

I am developing my first angular app and now when it has come to navigating on my page with routerLink, it does not work. It loads up with the welcome component, but when I click on a routerLink it sends me to a blank page.

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'pm-root',
  template: `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand">{{pageTitle}}</a>
    <ul class='nav nav-pills'>
      <li><a class="nav-link" routerLink='/welcome' routerLinkActive="active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" routerLink='/products' routerLinkActive="active">Product list</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  pageTitle: string = 'Acme Project Mangement';
}
```

And my app.module.ts looks like this

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProductList,
    ConvertToSpacesPipe,
    starComponent,
    ProductDetailComponent,
    WelcomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path: 'products', component: ProductListComponent},
      {path: 'products/:id', component: ProductDetailComponent},
      {path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent},
      {path: '', redirectTo: '/welcome', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: '**', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full'}
    ])
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I can not see any wrong with my code, and the compiler does not throw any error. Please help me so I can go on with angular.

Comment: RouterModule.forRoot has a second parameter where you can enable tracing for debugging purposes, e.g. [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45669030/how-to-trace-routing-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector for `pm-root` is not declared in the index.html, maybe is a typo most developer uses `app-root`.

```
<app-root>loading</app-root>
```

I copied your code, the only issue was the root component, looks the demo.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g2bcty?file=src/index.html

Comment: I have pm-root declared in index.html, I have tried  with changing the selector to app-root and declaring that in index.html. But it did not work. I have checked out your sollution and I see that you have made it work. So, the question is, why does this not work for me.

Comment: try to push your example to stackblitz, it is the only way to help you.

Comment: https://github.com/usken5000/APM-Start is where I have the code, god bless you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to also export the RouterModule in app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
  ProductList,
  ConvertToSpacesPipe,
  starComponent,
  ProductDetailComponent,
  WelcomeComponent
],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  RouterModule.forRoot([
    {path: 'products', component: ProductListComponent},
    {path: 'products/:id', component: ProductDetailComponent},
    {path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent},
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/welcome', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: '**', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full'}
  ])
],

bootstrap: [AppComponent]
exports: [
  RouterModule,
],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it did not work. :(